# Serial communication works only after screen

Tags: lua, serial-port, uart

I noticed strange behavior while programming with the serial UART interface.  First I set the right baud rate for the serial port.

```
stty-F /dev/ttyS0 speed 9600
```

Then I'm reading with LUA like:

```
 rserial=io.open('/dev/ttyS0','r')
 print (Reading)
 repeat
    local line=rserial:read(1)
    if line == "EOD" then
       EOD = true
       rserial:close()
    elseif line then
       lines = lines .. line
    end
 until EOD == true
 print (lines)
```

Normaly I only get "?" as answer. But then I tried to connect to the device via screen which worked fine.

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

After closing the screen connection I retried my LUA script and strangely enough suddenly it worked fine. Instead of the "?" I received an "OK".

And now finally to my question:
Does screen change any configuration I don know about? And if so how do I set them in LUA? I can't figure out what I am missing.
Thank you as always.
Best regards.

Comment: Surely you are now depending on screen to set all the *other* serial port parameters.  Like parity, stopbits, databits, handshaking, encoding.  You could probably use stty --all before and after to see what changed.

Comment: Hello Hans Passant. Thanks for the advice. I just tried it and it looks in both configurations almost the same. I noticed that in the working configuration sometimes the "-" is missing. Like:
Not working: opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
Working: -opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
Does that mean something?

Comment: @Zuendi if you use the same settings you should read the same.

Comment: But is there a difference between "opos" and "-opos"?